# Can't get the text from dynamically created buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please take a look at this [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bVZF7/15/).

I'm using `$('parentselector').on('click','selector', function(){` to bind the click event to dynamically created links so that when someone clicks on it, it'll show its value in the table. But the `html()` function is still returning the value from the old links. Can anyone point out what's the problem with the example?

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $('.area').each(function(){
   var area = $(this),
       selectbox = area.find('select'),
       show = area.find('.show'),   
       dialog_open =  $(this).find(".dialog_open")


   selectbox.change(function(){
    selectbox = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    show.html('<a href="#" onclick="javascript: return false" class="dialog_open">'+selectbox+'</a>')
    });
   show.on('click',dialog_open, function(){
      var dialog_open_text = dialog_open.text();
      $('td').html(dialog_open_text);
   });
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="area">
    <select>
        <option>Choose</option>
        <option>One</option>
        <option>Two</option>
    </select>
    <div class="show">
        <a class="dialog_open" onclick="javascript: return false" href="#">Three</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="area">
    <select>
        <option>Choose</option>
        <option>One</option>
        <option>Two</option>
    </select>
    <div class="show">
        <a class="dialog_open" onclick="javascript: return false" href="#">Four</a>
    </div>
</div>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title 1</th>
            <th>Title 2</th>
            <th>Title 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3MXY3/)**

Swapped your .on('click') for a .click() and select the values from the select boxes. :)

```
$(function(){
  $('.area').each(function(){
   var area = $(this),
       selectbox = area.find('select'),
       show = area.find('.show'),   
       dialog_open =  $(this).find(".dialog_open")


   selectbox.change(function(){
    var selectbox = $(this),
        value = selectbox.val();
        show.html('<a href="#" onclick="javascript: return false" class="dialog_open">' + value + '</a>');
    });
   show.click(function(){
      var dialog_open_text = $(this).siblings('select').val();
      $('td').html(dialog_open_text);
   });
  });
});
```

P.s. You should probably also check for $(document).ready() depending on what you're doing.

Comment: Updated JSfiddle again (HTML). :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're only defining the value of "dialog_open" when you're loading the page and by writing dialog_open.text() it's simply getting the "old" value. Change it to this:

```
show.on('click',dialog_open, function(){
    var dialog_open_text = $(this).find(".dialog_open").text();
    $('td').html(dialog_open_text);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/XCfAQ/

Answer (score 1):

We do this:

```
$('parentselector').on('click','selector', function(){
```

With the understanding that 'parentselector' is in the DOM when this binding is done. Otherwise we use:

```
$(document).on('click','selector', function(){
```

And ensure that this is done within DOM ready.